# sum values from db with array_sum() stuck at 3 loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, sum

after couple of days i finally got some values from 1st and 2nd line but after that at 4th line i got stacked and nothing works.

in need to get data from db where:

obrat |  memb     |  tab3.     | history

100. |  member1  |  0.         | 10

200   |  member2  |  member1. | 3

100   |  member3  |  member1. | 4

so if i will select from tab3 users which have my memb i need to sum their obrat and history. And doo the same think with them - select from tab3 where names are member1 and member2 and sum that.

my code:

```
while ($row = $resulto->fetch_assoc()) {


  $memb2 = $row['memb'];

    // second line member sel.

    $resulto2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tab3='$memb2' ") or die($mysqli->error());
    //pokud druhá linie
    if ($resulto2->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row2 = $resulto2->fetch_assoc()) {

           $memb3 = $row2['memb'];


        } // should be 3. line
        // get numbers from 2. line
        $resulto2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tab3='$memb2' ") or die($mysqli->error());

        $d = 0;
        $rows2 = array();
        $rows3c = array();
        while ($rowd = $resulto2->fetch_array()) {
            array_push($rows2, $rowd['obrat']);
            array_push($rows3c, $rowd['history']);

        }

        $array2 = array_sum($rows2);
        $count3 = array_sum($rows3c);

    }

}

//end / get values first line
$resulto = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tab3='$memb' ") or die($mysqli->error());

$d = 0;
$rows = array();
$rows2c = array();

while ($rowd = $resulto->fetch_array()) {
    array_push($rows, $rowd['obrat']);
    array_push($rows2c, $rowd['history']);

}
$array = array_sum($rows);
$count2 = array_sum($rows2c);
```

}

some idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

or next way iam trying to :

```
$resulto2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tab3='$memb' ") or die($mysqli->error());
```

if ($resulto2->num_rows > 0) {

```
while ($row2 = $resulto2->fetch_assoc()) {

  $memb2 = $row2['memb'];
    $resulto2a = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tab3='$memb2' ") or die($mysqli->error());


    while ($row2a = $resulto2a->fetch_assoc()) {

         $memb3 = " OR memb='".$row2a['memb']."'";
```

//here i need to get one value which is sum from all users selecting

```
}
```

}